# Проверка по шаблону

Tags: python, peewee

Хочу реализовать функцию проверки, в которую передается строка и далее эта строка сверяется с шаблонами из базы данных пока не будет найден подходящий или `false` если вообще ничего не найдено

Шаблон строки - это что-то типа `regex` но более упрощенно. Например:

- `"[Привет,Хеллоу,Добрый день,Здарова]"` - это все слова которые могут быть в входных данных, примеры:

  1. Входная строка: `"Здарова"` - true
  2. Входная строка: `"Привет"` - true
  3. Входная строка: `"Пока"` - false
- `*` - любое кол-во символов, шаблон: `[Привет,Хеллоу,Добрый день,Здарова], * [дела,жизнь,здоровье,семья]?`

  1. Входная строка: `"Здарова, как ты?"` - false
  2. Входная строка: `"Привет, как там твои дела?"` - true
  3. Входная строка: `"Добрый день, как ваше здоровье?"` - true
- `[:param]` - задаваемый параметр, шаблон `[Привет,Здарова], я [:name]"`
  Входная строка: `"Привет, я Человек"` - функция возвращает json `{name: "Человек"}`
- `~` слово с произвольным окончанием, шаблон: `[Прив~]`

  1. Входная строка: `"Прувет"` - false
  2. Входная строка: `"Привет"` - true
  3. Входная строка: `"Привот"` - true
  4. Входная строка: `"Прива"` - true
  5. Входная строка: `"Привандр"` - true

Дальше там еще много чего хотелось бы добавить, но для начала хотя-бы что-то из этого реализовать.

Для реализации я решил использовать полнотекстовый поиск, но так как я в базе не храню больших данных, а в основном записи базы данных будут строки шаблонов для проверки, я изменил немного подход:

1. Есть база данных в которой хранятся все шаблоны в виде: `{id: 1: template: '......'}`
2. Есть другая база где хранятся все слова из шаблона и id шаблонов где они встечаются: `{id:1, word: 'hello', id_temp: '1|5|16|23|43'}`

При добавлении шаблона в базу данных я удаляю все лишние символы и разбиваю строку на слова и получаю массив строк:

```
str = "[[Hello,Hi,Hey, Good day, Good Morning]] * [$[how are]$] [$[you]$]?"
str = str\
        .lower()\
        .replace('[[', ' ')\
        .replace(']]', ' ')\
        .replace('[$[', ' ')\
        .replace(']$]', ' ')\
        .replace(',', ' ')\
        .replace('*', ' ');

while '  ' in str:
    str = str.replace('  ', ' ')

print(str) #hello, hi, hey, good, day, good, morning, how, are, you
```

Далее идет добавление слов в базу, тут происходит проверка нет ли в базе уже каких-то слов. Если есть, то в поле `{id_temp: '...|id_new_temp'}` добавляю id нового шаблона, иначе добавляю само слово и id нового шаблона:

```
from tests.models import Words


def writeWord(word_to_write, temp_id):
    newWord = Words(word=word_to_write, temp_id=temp_id)
    newWord.save()


def findWord(word_to_find, new_temp_id):
    w = Words.select().where(Words.word == word_to_find)
    if w:
        print(w)
    else:
        writeWord(word_to_find, new_temp_id)


id = 2
str = 'Hello my friend'
word = str.lower().split(' ')

for s in word:
    findWord(s, id)
```

Используется `peewee`

Процесс добавления шаблона на этом заканчивается. Далее, поиск строки в базе шаблонов, кода еще нет, но алгоритм не сложный:

1. Получаю строку, разбиваю на слова и получаю массив строк
2. Ищу каждое слово в базе слов, из найденных записей беру поле `id_temp` и тоже разбиваю и записываю в словарь: `{'id': count}`
3. В дальнейшем при добавлении в словарь новых `id` проверяется нет ли такого `id` там, если есть, то увеличивается `count`, иначе добавляется запись в словарь с `count=1`
4. После того, как по всем словам было произведено поиск по базе, я беру словарь и ищу запись с самым большим значением `count` это и будет `id` шаблона, который вероятнее всего подойдет для входной строки.

Вопрос был такой: нет ли какого-нибудь определенного подхода для решения данной задачи или как оптимизировать алгоритм велосипеда, который я тут собрал. Например, если одно слово будет встречаться в 2000 шаблонах, то запись этого слова в базе будет громоздким `{id: 35, word: 'hello', 'id_temp': '1|2|3|523|2323|32|123|124|345|234|133|234|123|234|123|42|545......'}` - как это можно оптимизировать?

Comment: В чем проблема? Покажите код.

Comment: @DmitryErohin проблема в подходе и наиболее оптимальном способе реализации. Дополнил вопрос.